# How is it called when you apply min / max seperatly to each dimension?

Tags: functions, terminology

I want to do the following:

$$\begin{pmatrix}3\\1\\4\\1\end{pmatrix} = \min(
\begin{pmatrix}4\\4\\4\\4\end{pmatrix}, 
\begin{pmatrix}3\\1\\4\\10000\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}10\\10\\10\\10\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}10\\10\\10\\1\end{pmatrix})$$

So I have many vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and I want to describe that I apply the min-function seperately to each dimension to get a new vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is there a common function / a better way to describe it thant "apply min separately to each dimension"?

Comment: The notations $v \wedge w$ (for minimum) and $v \vee w$ (for maximum) are common for the lattice $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or for any lattice for that matter).  For a finite subset $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ you can write $\bigwedge U$ and $\bigvee U$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\{v^j\}$ are your vectors, with components $v^j_i$, and $w$ is your new vector, with components $w_i$, then

$$
w_i = \min_j v^j_i.
$$

Comment: That's a nice formal way to describe it (+1), but isn't there a name for that?

Comment: "component-wise min/max", maybe. There may be another name for that, but it's either something I'm not aware of or not recalling.